# Ошибка отправки электронных писем на Java (JavaMail)

Tags: java, email, javamail

Я хочу сделать утилиту для отправки электронных писем. Нашел библиотеку JavaMail. Скачал её и нашел простенькую программу на ней. Я воспользовался eclipse для написания кода, он ошибок в синтаксисе не нашел. Вот код:

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SendEmail {
    final String senderEmailID = "myemailt@gmail.com";
    final String senderPassword = "admin";
    final String emailSMTPserver = "smtp.gmail.com";
    final String emailServerPort = "465";
    String receiverEmailID = null;
    static String emailSubject = "Test Mail";
    static String emailBody = ":)";

    public SendEmail(
            String receiverEmailID,
            String emailSubject,
            String emailBody
    ) {
        this.receiverEmailID = receiverEmailID;
        this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
        this.emailBody = emailBody;
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", senderEmailID);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", emailSMTPserver);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", emailServerPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", emailServerPort);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
        try {
            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setText(emailBody);
            msg.setSubject(emailSubject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmailID));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(receiverEmailID));
            Transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("Message send Successfully:)");
        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(senderEmailID, senderPassword);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SendEmail mailSender = new
                SendEmail("my2email@gmail.com", emailSubject, emailBody);
    }
}
```

При компиляции вылетает ошибка:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class SendEmail
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Решение находится в очень неожиданном месте, а именно: при работе с google mail необходимо вот здесь включить опцию "Небезопасные приложения заблокированы" по  ссылке: `https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1`

Comment: Уже включены небезопасные приложения, ошибка была в установленной библиотеке, не было пару пакетов, но спасибо за ответ)